# Simple makefile not producing output file(Correctly)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, makefile

I have a simple make file as such:

```
all:
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror ListImplementation.c ListType.h ListInterface.h  test.c -o test.out

    gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror ListImplementation.c ListType.h ListInterface.h  sort.c -o sort.out
```

Where test.c is a file reliant on those other c files, and headerfiles.
The same goes for sort.c.

Now after typing "make" it compiles, however in my text editor (gedit),
sort.c is color coded blue for some reason. As such when I look in the directory (On Ubuntu after running make), test.out works fine (it's green color coded, but sort.out does not (it's white). Trying to run ./sort.out does not work as the file never turned into an output file, despite the name change, what could be going wrong here?

Comment: You don't compile the headers directly; they are compiled when they're included in a source file.  Leave them off the command lines.  One advantage of that (apart from it being correct) is that the far ends of the lines can be seen without scrolling.

Comment: part of `make` syntax is whitespaces, make sure that you have TAB character between start of line and `gcc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succinctly, the whole structure of the `makefile` is wrong.  For the code shown, you should be using something like:

```
PROG1 = test
PROG2 = sort
PROGRAMS = ${PROG1} ${PROG2}

LIST.c = ListImplementation.c
TEST.c = test.c
SORT.c = sort.c

LIST.o = ${LIST.c:.c=.o}
SORT.o = ${SORT.c:.c=.o}
TEST.o = ${TEST.c:.c=.o}

all: ${PROG1} ${PROG2}

${PROG1}: ${LIST.o} ${TEST.o}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${LIST.o} ${TEST.o} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}

${PROG2}: ${LIST.o} ${SORT.o}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${LIST.o} ${SORT.o} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}

${LIST.o}: ListType.h ListInterface.h
${SORT.o}: ListType.h ListInterface.h
${TEST.o}: ListType.h ListInterface.h
```

This will work with pretty much any version of `make`.  It assumes that the `make` program will define a C compiler in macro `CC`, that it defines compilation flags in macro `CFLAGS`, loader flags in macro `LDFLAGS` and libraries in `LDLIBS`.  It assumes that `make` can deduce that it can create `sort.o` from `sort.c` using a built-in rule equivalent to:

```
sort.o: sort.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ sort.c
```

where the `-o $@` might not be specified on the command line.

If you're using GNU `make`, there are shorthands available that are not used.  Often, I'd define a macro for the object files for a program and then use the in the dependency list and in the linker command line.  Also, with GNU `make`, you could usefully add:

```
.PHONY: all
```

to tell `make` that there shouldn't be an actual file called `all` around.

Now, when you run `make`, it looks to find `all`.  When it doesn't find it, it makes it by ensuring the dependencies, `${PROG1}` and `${PROG2}` are each up to date, and then executing the (empty) list of commands for the `all` target.  To make `${PROG1}`, it finds the rule, ensures the dependencies are up to date, and then runs the (non-empty) list of commands to create the `${PROG1}` target.